# Google Charts Drawing in All Browsers but Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-visualization

Internet Explorer is a child of the devil!

Now for the real problem, I have a program pulling information from an external database which is then being converted into an array and drawn out in google charts. The charts draw perfect in every single browser, except internet explorer. Unfortunately, it's a problem that needs to be solved since a large amount of people using this program are using IE.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
var dataArray = JSON.parse(data2);
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

// Declare columns
data.addColumn('datetime', dataArray[0][0]);
data.addColumn('number', dataArray[0][1]);

// Add data
for(var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
    data.addRow([new Date(dataArray[i][0]), parseFloat(dataArray[i][1])]);
}

var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    fractionDigits: 5
});

formatter.format(data, 1);

// Format Chart
var options = {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    hAxis: { format: 'MMM d, y', gridlines: { count: 12 }, slantedText:true, slantedTextAngle:90, textStyle : {fontSize: 12} },
    vAxis: { title: 'Index Rate' },
    timeline: { groupByRowLabel: true }
};

//Draw Chart
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

The data for the array and columns being added are all correct, as the chart is drawing perfectly fine in all of the other browsers. I am loading two js scripts: "https://www.google.com/jsapi" and "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js".

When Internet Explorer is used, either a blank graph with no data points is drawn or the error message "You called the draw() method with the wrong type of data rather than a DataTable or DataView" shows up in a red error box instead of the graph.

Has anyone ever had a problem with Google Charts not drawing in all browsers and know how to fix this problem?

Thank you everyone in advance!

Comment: Basically, the function is being called upon button click. Dropdown inputs are read upon submit, data is being pulled for the chart, and then it is being drawn directly after.

I updated the library loader with no luck. Just a blank chart with no datapoints is being drawn.

Comment: Which IE version you are using? If it is IE8 then there are sometimes problems in Internet Explorer 8 .Reason: IE8 doesn't support SVG, so Charts fails over into VML, IE8's JavaScript doesn't allow trailing commas in lists.